# How to avoid multiple colorbars when looping seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, colorbar

I made 3 plots in a for loop with the following code. But the first figure I create has 3 colorbars, the 2nd has 2 and the 1st has 1. So it seems the previous plot adds a colorbar to the current plot. How can I avoid this?

```
for f in files:
    #print(f)
    roi_signals = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')
   
    fig = sns.heatmap(roi_signals)
    fig_name = f.replace('.txt', '.png')
    plt.savefig(fig_name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, [`sns.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) plots onto the existing Axes and allocates space for a colorbar:

> This will draw the heatmap into the currently-active Axes if none is provided to the `ax` argument. Part of this Axes space will be taken and used to plot a colormap, unless `cbar` is False or a separate Axes is provided to `cbar_ax`.

---

The simplest solution is to clear the figure each iteration with [`plt.clf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clf.html):

```
for f in files:
    roi_signals = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')

    sns.heatmap(roi_signals)
    plt.savefig(f.replace('.txt', '.png')
    plt.clf() # clear figure before next iteration
```

Or specify `cbar_ax` to overwrite the previous iteration's colorbar:

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    roi_signals = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')

    cbar_ax = fig.axes[-1] if i else None # retrieve previous cbar_ax (if exists)
    sns.heatmap(roi_signals, cbar_ax=cbar_ax)
    plt.savefig(f.replace('.txt', '.png')
```

Or just create a new figure per iteration, but this is not recommended for many iterations:

```
for f in files:
    roi_signals = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')

    fig = plt.figure() # create new figure each iteration
    sns.heatmap(roi_signals)
    plt.savefig(f.replace('.txt', '.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it with this:

```
import matlabplot.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

for f in files:
    #print(f)
    roi_signals = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = sns.heatmap(roi_signals)
    fig_name = f.replace('.txt', '.png')
    plt.savefig(fig_name)
```

Comment: This works but creates a new `Figure` object on every iteration. I suggest using just 1 figure and clearing it each iteration with `plt.clf()`.